# cmake . -B build - Compiling Neural Graphic Primitives

Tags: cmake

I trying compile NGP but after cmake . -B build I get this lines:

I've installed
Visual Studio 2019
CUDA Toolkit 11.6
CMake 3.22
Python 3.10
Optix 7.6

```
C:\NGP\instant-ngp>cmake . -B build
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30147.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30147.0
-- The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 11.6.124
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CUDA compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CUDA compiler: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.6/bin/nvcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CUDA compile features
-- Detecting CUDA compile features - done
-- **Obtained CUDA architectures automatically from installed GPUs**
**CMake Error: The source directory "SOURCES/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp" does not exist.**
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
CMake Error at dependencies/tiny-cuda-nn/CMakeLists.txt:107 (try_run):
  Failed to configure test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  dependencies/tiny-cuda-nn/CMakeLists.txt:146 (TCNN_AUTODETECT_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/NGP/instant-ngp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I am not coder I just want to try NERF. It ss possible download somewhere compiled NGP or it doesn't work that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Noticed that OP is using the `-S` flag implicitly the issue seems to be elsewhere, hence the updated answer:

UPDATED ANSWER

Please bare in mind that with the limited information at my disposal. This is again only a wild guess, based on what I tried.

After re-examining the output of CMake I've noticed that the issue is within one of the dependencies i.e.

```
CMake Error at dependencies/tiny-cuda-nn/CMakeLists.txt:107 (try_run):
```

I was not able to completely replicate the problem, however I do believe I know how to debug these issues. My wild guess here is that either:

1. The individual dependencies were incorrectly pulled or
2. The CMake files were poorly generated due to some issue and you didn't clean them.

I would recommend trying the following:

1. Delete the build folder, and run `cmake -S. -Bbuild` again. And if that fails you can try the second option.
2. Remove the git repository (folder called `instant-ngp`) and clone it again using **exactly this command:**

   `git clone --recursive https://github.com/nvlabs/instant-ngp`

Please note that the `--recursive` option is very important due to the fact that you need to pull the dependant repositories as well.

Now if all of that fails. You still have one more option and that is to go to the folder `dependencies/tiny-cuda-nn/` and generate the `CMake files` yourself, however I do not recommend that due to the fact that if you have limited experience you may not know what exactly to do.

I've also checked the variables you wanted to set, and you may do that by running this in Powershell
`$Env:CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES=YOUR_VALUE_HERE` (in my case it is `75` because I have a `RTX2080`). However bare in mind that

1. You shouldn't need it, because the architecture is discovered for you
2. You need to delete the build folder in order to clean up the cached `CMake` files

Hope it helps!

Comment: I forgot to metion that "SOURCES/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp" exist all the time and after "cmake . -B build" command - build directory is filled with 
CMakeFiles dir
dependencies dir and
CMakeCache.txt

I was thinking about this line "Obtained CUDA architectures automatically from installed GPUs" TCNN_AUTODETECT_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES - isn't there some problem with autodetecting cuda architectures? Should I write some values manually?

Comment: Ah I see now, you are using the -S flag implicitly. No I would definitely not set any values manually unless you are 100% sure you know what you are doing. The whole point of the CMake files is to make everything easier for you in the sense of setting up and linking the binaries. The question is how the CMake file is written and if you are doing this from the correct folder. Can you update your question with the folder structure? In general `SOURCES/CMakeFiles/` caught my eye and seems weird.

Comment: I will update my answer now, I think I understand where is the issue.

Comment: 0

I deleted all files and started git clone again. Fortunatelly it finally works "cmake . -B build" and than "cmake --build build --config RelWithDebInfo -j". But it didn't create testbed.exe in /build directory for final step.

Comment: You will have to give more info than that for us to help.

Comment: Instead of "testbed.exe" it generated "instant-ngp.exe" so it works! Thank you for your help and time I really Appreciate it :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I fixed my `SOURCES/CMakeFiles` error by upgrading CMake from version 3.22 to 3.28.